# Grouping data on the basis of Parent Value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have group of attributes configured in the system under different Headings and the data in the database is stored as following.

```
Type   |Attribute Name|Sort Order|
-------|--------------|----------|
Heading|Cars          |         1|
Text   |BMW           |         2|
Text   |Ford          |         3|
Text   |Honda         |         4|
Heading|Trucks        |         5|
Text   |Asphalt       |         6|
Text   |BMW           |         7|
Text   |Daimler       |         8|
```

I want to add a new column in result pane and assign Heading to following attributes lies below based on the sort order as shown below. Attribute Group will actually determine which attribute lies in which Heading so while migrating data it is easier to configure in new system.

```
Type|   Attribute Name| Attribute Group|    Sort Order|
Text    BMW             Cars                2
Text    Ford            Cars                3
Text    Honda           Cars                4
Text    Asphalt         Trucks              6
Text    BMW             Trucks              7
Text    Daimler         Trucks              8
```

Can someone help or direct me in a direction how can i achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL Developer is just a client. Tag the actual DBMS you use.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to identify the `sort_order` for the most recent row that has a `heading`.  Then you can join back to the table to fill in the information you want:

```
select t.*, th.attribute_name
from (select t.*,
             max(case when type = 'Heading' then sort_order end) over (order by sort_order) as heading_sort_order
      from t
     ) left join
     t th
     on th.sort_order = t.heading_sort_order
where th.type <> 'Heading';
```

Oracle supports the `IGNORE NULL`s keyword.  So, an alternative method is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(case when type = 'Heading' then attribute_name end ignore nulls) over (order by sort_order) as heading_attribute_name
      from t
     ) t
where th.type <> 'Heading';
```